# How to increase alphanumeric column values by 1 increment in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, datatables

I have this table and I would like to increase the value in 'column2' by 1. I just want to increase the number, not progress the letter. Also, 'column2' is a copy of 'column1', the only difference being 'column2' has an added value of +1.

Current table:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | a1 |
| a2 | a2 |
| a3 | a3 |

Desired result:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | a2 |
| a2 | a3 |
| a3 | a4 |

How do I add +1 and apply that methodology to column2 entirely? It seems really simple but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Thanks

Comment: In what format is your table data?

Comment: how are you reading in the table? csv, pandas etc. show some code, even if it's broken

Comment: My table is pulled from MySQL server using SQL.SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE "a1" OR column1 LIKE "a2" OR column1 LIKE "a3" and so on so forth

Comment: Is your 2nd column always a single letter followed by a number or can it contain multiple letters such as ab23?

Comment: It's always a single letter followed by a single number.

Comment: are you using a dataframes in python, or just sql. Calrify how you want to acheive.

Comment: im using the dataframes in python. i pulled the data i wanted using SQL from the MySQL database and those tables are stored as python dataframes where i manipulate the data.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always one letter and one integer, as you mentioned in comments, then you can do the following (df is your dataframe):

```
df['column2']=df['column2'].apply(lambda x: x[0]+str(int(x[1])+1))

print(df)
```

result:

```
  column1 column2
0      a1      a2
1      a2      a3
2      a3      a4
```